# TypeError: reply is not a function

Tags: javascript, node.js, hapi.js

Using Hapi v17, I am just trying to make a simple web API to start building my knowledge, but I keep getting an error every time I test the GET methods built out.  Below is the code I am running:

```
'use strict';
const Hapi = require('hapi');
const MySQL = require('mysql');

//create a serve with a host and port

const server = new Hapi.Server({
   host: 'serverName',
   port: 8000
});

const connection = MySQL.createConnection({
     host: 'host',
     user: 'root',
     password: 'pass',
     database: 'db'
});

connection.connect();

//add the route
server.route({
   method: 'GET',
   path: '/helloworld',
   handler: function (request, reply) {
   return reply('hello world');
}
});

server.start((err) => {
   if (err) {
      throw err;
   }
   console.log('Server running at:', server.info.uri);
});
```

Below is the error I am getting:

```
Debug: internal, implementation, error 
    TypeError: reply is not a function
    at handler (/var/nodeRestful/server.js:26:11)
```

I am unsure as to why there is an issue calling the reply function, but it is a fatal error as of right now.

Comment: What does `console.log(reply)` outputs ?

Comment: @3Dos it prints the following: `{"statusCode":500,"error":"Internal Server Error","message":"An internal server error occurred"}`

Comment: @MikaelLennholm the spacing is just off by a line I believe.  The error occurs on the line `return reply('hello world');`

Comment: Could you add `console.log('Type', typeof reply)` above the erroring line and see what gets logged?

Comment: @Drew And therefore, you can tell the server side responded with an internal error code (500) So here, the javascript is not the issue, `/helloworld` is. What does this path return? Is there even anything that is responding there? Do you fully understand your code?

Comment: @3Dos The server responds with 500 **because** of the error described in the question, i.e. that `reply is not a function` in the handler for the `/helloworld` route. This is entirely consistent with the issue described in the question so no other revelation has been made here.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Version 17 of Hapi has a quite different API.

https://hapijs.com/api/17.1.0

Route handlers are no longer passed the `reply` function as the second argument, instead they are passed something called the [*Response Toolkit*](https://github.com/hapijs/hapi/blob/master/API.md#response-toolkit) which is an object containing properties and utilities for taking care of the response.
With the new API you don't even have to use the Response Toolkit to return a simple text response as in your case, you can simply return the text from the handler:

```
//add the route
server.route({
  method: 'GET',
  path: '/helloworld',
  handler: function (request, h) {
    return 'hello world';
  }
});
```

The Response Toolkit is used to customize the response, such as setting the content type. Ex:

```
  ...
  handler: function (request, h) {
    const response = h.response('hello world');
    response.type('text/plain');
    return response;
  }
```

---

**Note:** with this new API, `server.start()` doesn't take a callback function and if you provide one anyway it won't get invoked (you may have noticed that the `console.log()` in your callback function never happen). Now, `server.start()` returns a Promise instead which can be used to verify that the server started properly.

I believe this new API is designed to be used with `async-await` syntax.

Comment: Even the new documentation has bugs! I guess they are still working on it. But they should at least fix the Hello World part since new users have trouble getting around it.

Answer (score 3):

To solve this problem you just need to replace `return reply('hello world');` with `return 'hello world';`
Here is the description below:

According to hapi v17.x they Replaced the reply() interface with a new lifecycle methods interface:

1. removed response.hold() and response.resume().
2. methods are async and the required return value is the response.
3. a response toolkit (h) is provided with helpers (instead of the reply() decorations).

Answer (score 0):

It seems you have duplication in your code:

```
const server = new Hapi.Server({
   host: 'serverName',
   port: 8000
});

// Create a server with a host and port
// This second line is not needed!!! and probably is causing the error 
//you described
const server = new Hapi.Server();
```

Comment: I added that line by accident, early I fixed it right after posting.  I have updated the question now, but still get the same error after that fix